# Raster to vector convertion google earth engine: error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in table3

Tags: google-earth-engine

link of code is "https://code.earthengine.google.com/821c1e554cf91c5be96467a3e17f39f5". My final task is convert raster image into vector data. But When Executing the code following error is occured "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in table3",

```
var count = sorted.size(); 
print(count)

var ndwi1 = sorted.map(
function(img) {
var img1 = img.clip(table2)
var ndwi = img1.normalizedDifference(['B3','B5']);
var thres = ndwi.gt(0.15).rename('thres');



var slop = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation.clip(table2));
var slope1 = slop.lt(20).rename('slope1');
var slope_m = slope1.updateMask(slope1);
//var and1 = ee.Image.and(thres,shadow);

var shadowMap=ee.Terrain.hillshade(elevation.clip(table2), img.get('SUN_AZIMUTH'),img.get('SUN_ELEVATION'));
var shadow = shadowMap.lt(255).rename('shadow');

var evi1 = thres.expression('(thr>0) && (shd >0) && (slp>0)? 1 : 0' , 

{
 'thr' : thres,
 'shd' : shadow,
 'slp' : slope1
});

var evi = evi1.clip(table2);
var vectors = evi.addBands(evi).reduceToVectors({
reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
geometry: 'table3',
crs : evi.projection(),
scale: 1000,





}); 

return vectors;
})





Map.addLayer(ndwi1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var vectors = evi.addBands(evi).reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: 'table3',
  crs : evi.projection(),
  scale: 1000,
});
```

`'table3'` is a string, not any kind of geometry. Since `table3` is a variable, you shouldn't be quoting it.

---

There are several other errors observable in your script once this is fixed — if you're having trouble understanding them, I strongly recommend that you make an effort to **simplify the script so that it demonstrates the problem in a simple way** rather than asking for help with your entire work in progress. Not only will this make it easier for others to help you, it will often help you recognize and solve the problem on your own.

Comment: I have modify the code which easier to understand everyone. But again  one error occur "error.Layer 1: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Invalid type.
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. 
Actual type: FeatureCollection". My link is https://code.earthengine.google.com/39315f9591a11b5b0bdd3ec4f443bee4